# Is there a way to capture/log installations and installation errors caused by the tasksel?

Tags: apt, kali-linux, aws, cloud-init

I have an automation script that involves this line:

```
:~$ sudo tasksel install desktop-xfce meta-top10 meta-default
tasksel: apt-get failed (100)
```

But I am unsure why `tasksel` failed. Is there a way to capture the progress of the `tasksel` and find a verbose error message?

Checking `/var/log/apt/term.log` only shows `Error were encountered while processing` for `/tmp/apt-dpkg-install ... mariadb-server`, but it does not list what the error was or how to fix it. In my specific case, rerunning the command works, but for the future, I would like to know how to find a verbose error message for `tasksel`.

**Note**:

```
:~$ sudo apt install desktop-xfce^ meta-top10^ meta-default^
```

simply leads to `Couldn't find task` for each package name.

I am currently using `Kali Linux 2020.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is looking at https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/tasksel/-/tree/kali/master/kali-tasks and then replacing the `sudo tasksel install` with its equivalent `sudo apt-get`. In my use case, I used

```
sudo apt-get install kali-desktop-xfce kali-linux-core kali-tools-top10 kali-linux-default
```

This way, I have a clearer error message. Nevertheless, I have never had `apt-get` fail while `tasksel` still fails on occasion, so I know what I will be using in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You received an error because the names of tasks isn't set correctly.

To list tasks with the exact names use:

```
tasksel --list-tasks
```

the `i` at the beginning of tasks name mean that the package is installed, `u` = task isn't installed.

Here is an example to see the difference between debian and kali (xfce)

On debian: the task name is `xfce-desktop`

On kali : the name is different `task-xfce-desktop`

The command should be:

```
sudo apt install task-xfce-desktop
```

Comment: I have double check the names in https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/tasksel/-/tree/kali/master/kali-tasks. Those names came running `tasksel --list-tasks` some time ago, though currently, `tasksel --list-tasks` returns an error of `Can't use string ("Kali core packages") as an ARRAY refer while "strict refs" in use at /usr/bin/tasksel`.Running `sudo tasksel install desktop-xfce` on its own works fine; running the `tasksel install` command individually for each package alone seems to work fine.